# HTML question: Percentage-sized elements with minimum pixel dimensions

Tags: html, css

I have a page with elements that I want to be dynamically resizeable with the browser window, but I don't want certain elements squishing shorter than certain dimensions.  Without Javascript, is there a good way to do this?

**Edit:** Argh!  Stupid question.  I should've remembered that sooner. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

min-width and min-height might accomplish this, but I don't believe IE6 supports them.